# Method = "OST"?

Tags: forms, tomcat, encoding

We have some clients who, upon attempting to submit a form, are recieving the error - "HTTP Status 501  Method OST is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API" being thrown by Apache Tomcat/6.0.29.. Apparently, this error is only being received by users running Firefox on Windows 7.

After a lot of digging, the vast majority of examples of Method = "OST" that I can find are on Chinese language websites.. Like [here](http://biancheng.dnbcw.info/linux/375491.html).. In [This discussion](http://www.justskins.com/forums/missing-first-chareacter-after-107510.html) (English language) "Quoted Printable Transfer Encoding" was mentioned as the possible cause of a similar problem, but it does not involve Apache Tomcat, or any particular browser/operating system combination.

I have a feeling that this issue is something to do with encoding, but have little experience relating to this.. Has anyone experienced a similar issue, or perhaps have some suggestions as to how I might go about solving it?

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday. It happened on Tomcat 6 and my client is Chrome 18 on Windows 7 64-bit. I [posted](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/chrome/OST$20not$20supported/chrome/cdCz6c7wXnY/nBba-XA7pj4J) it on Google Chrome forums. It becomes weirder, because the problem did repeat when I tested at work - the exact same form running on the same server!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be useful to have a look at the following **known** and recorded defect in Mozilla Firefox:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=723805

This seems relevant to your problem, and it may shed some light on how you could do things a bit differently to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. Sounds about right to me. Just need to tell them to upgrade to FF9.

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help. Good luck!